# Xcode 14.2 Simulator shows black screen after Run project two-three times

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-simulator

There is one old project run on Xcode 14.2 and the Simulator shows a black screen after Running the project two-three times once clears all data and restarts System then run it works again 2-3 times and then got the same issue.

If there is any way to fix this issue let help me

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check Project Configuration: Verify that your project's settings are correctly configured for the Simulator. Make sure the target deployment version matches the Simulator's iOS version, and check for any specific Simulator-related settings that might be affecting the display.

Comment: @ChiragSondagar , yes project's settings are correctly configured but the simulator is not load after a successful run 2-3 times.